# Working with two models in one view with mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Let's imagine we have two models:

```
Teams: Id, Name
Player: Id, Name, TeamId
```

I want to save a team and player collection of this team on one view. So there must be these element in my view:

- input for team name
- input for player name
- add button to add player name from input to collection
- a list of added players
- save button to save the team and player's collection.

In this situation, we should work with two models on one view. Especially, I want to see how add button scenario should be.

Can anyone help about that?

Comment: You need to combine the two into one model. Either by making one model with those two models as properties, or making an all new model with all of the same properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would typically use a view model for this that decomposes into (maps to) your entity models.  The model might look like:

```
 public class MeamWithPlayersViewModel
 {
      public long ID { get; set; }  // this ought to match the id parameter on the post
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public TeamPlayer[] Players { get; set; }
 }

 public class TeamPlayer
 {
      public long PlayerID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

In your view -- assuming you add players for a specific team --

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
       <p>Current Players</p>
       @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Players.Length; ++i)
       {
             <p>Model.Players[i].Name
             @Html.HiddenFor( model => model.Players[i].PlayerID )
             </p>
       }
       <button class="add-player">Add Player</button>
       <button class="save-button">Save</button>
 }
```

Then using some javascript with AJAX you'd implement the ability to add a new player from a list retrieved via AJAX.  In the callback from the add player code (tied to the button), you'd add the name and another hidden field with the player's id `<input type="hidden" name="Players[n].PlayerID" value="_some_id_" />`, where `n` is the next number in the sequence.  You might be able to omit `n` depending on your exact functionality.

Comment: I've try this method but I crashed at add button. When I click add button, how can I take the name from player input and add it to collection stored on controller?

Comment: @mavera  - your save button should post back to an action that takes the view model as input (only the ids will be populated).  Then you can use these to pull in the property entity models, update, and save them.